# How to specify one or more items from base model are present in the request body

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I have a FastApi application that has the following base model:

```
class Mint(BaseModel):
    investigation: Union[Investigation, None] = None
    dataset: Union[List[Dataset], None] = None
    datafile: Union[List[Datafile], None] = None
```

So the Request takes one investigation or one or more datasets or datafiles.
How can I change it so one of these HAS to be included in the request body but none of them are madatory?

For example, the body can contain:

- 1 Investigation and 2 datasets
- 1 Investigation
- 2 datasets
- 4 datafiles

thanks

Comment: OP is specific to pydantic @fukanchik

Comment: Yes, same here https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/506

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using the `@root_validator` tag

```
@root_validator()
    def check_contents(cls, values):
        if (values.get('investigation') is None) and \
                (values.get('dataset') is None) and \
                (values.get('datafile') is None):
            raise ValueError('either an investigation or a dataset or a datafile is required')
        return values
```